# In android failed to connect to /local ip address

Tags: android, retrofit2

In the android code, I used the local IP address. But after running the code, in my device, the local IP address is not connected. It is showing error like

`failed to connect to /aaa.bbb.c.xx7 (port 8085) from /aaa.bbb.c.xx6 (port 47380) after 10000ms`

In my device IP address is showing as ***aaa.bbb.c.xx6*** but in my system ip address showing as ***aaa.bbb.c.xx7***

I am unable to find what was the issue?

Can I change any retrofit settings?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using pro-guard rules in your app. Add these lines to your `proguard-rules.pro` (or if you're using `custom-rules.pro` file) files to solve the issue.

```
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp3.**

-dontwarn okio.**
```

Proguard rules file path `<project_root>\app\proguard-rules.pro`

For more info refer this Retrofit's official proguard rules [file](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro)